# Write to entity framework database within Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

How can I save something to my database in the entity framework within a separate thread?
What I want to do could look like that, but obviously doesn't work like that:

```
public class ThingsHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

    private void ProcessThing()
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thing dbThing = db.Things.Where(...).AsEnumerable().LastOrDefault();
            dbThing.some_property = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I hope, I was able to make clear, what I would like to achieve. But what do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with task, you should place context initialization inside task:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
        var db = new DatabaseContext();
        Thing dbThing = db.Things.Where(...).AsEnumerable().LastOrDefault();
        dbThing.some_property = true;
        db.SaveChanges();
}
```

But if you use EF6, you might want to use Async methods:

```
private async void ProcessThing()
{        
    Thing dbThing = await db.Things.Where(...).AsEnumerable().LastOrDefaultAsync();
    dbThing.some_property = true;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: I already tried your first solution before and strangely, nothing was saved to the database. Do you have any explanation for this?

Comment: @sk904861 Well, I would suggest you to add .Wait() at the end of task and check if it works.

Comment: With `.Wait()` it works. I also tried your suggestion using the async method, but then I get the error `Cannot await Thing`.

Comment: @sk904861 Unfortunately i can't suggest you anything else

Comment: Have you tried `await` in combination with Linq? Apparently they don't go together very well.